# Django tag template for date

Tags: django, django-templates

from an API, I got a date which is rendered like this with `{{ value }}`: 2014-03-25T15:51:29Z

I'd like to display it in a more fancy way but with the tag `{{ value|date:'D d M Y' }}`, nothing is displayed... Should I somehow specify the input date format? Cheers

Comment: Are you sure `value` is a `datetime` object and not a string?

Comment: Could it be that the date you got from the api is a string and needs to be parsed into a `datetime.datetime`?

Comment: Yes it is a string, I was hoping some django magic string to datetime directly in the template tag workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `value` isn't a `datetime` object but rather a string. You'll need to convert it in your view before you can process it in the template.

There are several ways to do this, see [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python) for many examples.

So if your view has:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime 

def my_view(request):
    date_str = '2014-03-25T15:51:29Z'
    # must convert to datetime object
    date = datetime(*map(int, re.split('[^\d]', date_str)[:-1]))
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'date': date})
```

Only then you can do:

```
{{ date|date:'D d M Y' }}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I was secretly praying not to work in the view. Cause I have a lot of these string date and they are deeply nested in an object. But it seems it's the only solution. Cheers.

Comment: @abrunet - yep. the `date` tempalte filter won't operate on anything that isn't a `datetime` object.